# Can I change my string?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` populated with strings in the form:

```
Name - (###)###-####
or
Name - ##########
```

I want to leave it in the form without the name or the hyphen:

```
##########
```

I did the following:

```
for (String number : contactArrayList) {
    number = number.replace("(", "");
    number = number.replace(")", "");
    number = number.replace(" ", "");
    number = number.replace ("+", "");
    number = number.replaceAll("\\D+", ""); //Remove non numeric values

    sendMessage(number, "SMS")
}
```

`sendSMS` method:

```
private void sendSMS(String number, String message) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
}
```

But this created the instance of my string, `number`, 5 times (I know because any message sent to that number is sent 5 times). Is there a way I can combine all of these replace statements?

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: Your last replace has the comment stating `Remove non numeric values`, why not use that single replace?

Comment: The code you've provided should not create a string 5 times, perhaps there is something else going on. Have you included all of the pertinent code?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Hmm... You're right. After doing what you have suggested, it still continues to send more than one SMS. I will update my question.

Comment: The sendMessage() is inside the for loop if I'm not mistaken. Bad!

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Do you want to store the phone number (without non numeric values) back into the `ArrayList` or another list? What you're doing now doesn't make much sense, you're effectively setting `number` equal to the last entry in the `contactArrayList` after iterating over the whole list.

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty simple. It will replace all the non-numeric values:

```
for (String number : contactArrayList) {
    number = number.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""); //Remove non numeric values
}
```

Comment: @JonnyHenly : Oh! I think he thinks that because of five replace statements, he has 5 strings, and that's why sms is being sent multiple time? I don't know I am just guessing.

Comment: It's not your fault at all. Yea that's what I was thinking as well.

Answer (score 3):

Just use your final replace statement.  The rest can be removed.

```
number = number.replaceAll("\\D+", ""); //Remove non numeric values
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions.

```
String str= "Name - (132)892-0121";
    str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d]*", "");
```

As you want only the digits, eliminate all non-digits from the string.